# VCF files to Galaxy S7

Tags: contacts, import

I have a *Samsung Galaxy S7* running Android version 7 (Kernel Version is 3.18.14.12365438). I want to import my PC contacts from Outlook 2007 or my iPhone 6S. I also generated the `.vcf` files, which include photos of the contacts.

All the files have been in the download folder on the phone. How to continue and update the contacts?

Answer (score 0):

As you have the contacts in form of `.vcf` file(s), you can use the *Contacts* app's native import functionality:

1. Start the contacts app
2. Tap the "3-dot-menu" (top-right of the screen)
3. From the drop-down menu that opens, chose "import/export"¹
4. On the next page, chose "Import from SD card"²
5. A file browser should open and let you chose the file to import. Pick your `.vcf` file
6. Now your contacts should be imported. If you have multiple files, repeat above steps.

[image: screenshots]
<sup>Visualisation of the process (click image for larger variant)</sup>

---

¹ <sub>if there is no "import/export" directly in that menu, check the sub-menus – e.g. *Manage contacts* or *Settings*</sub>
² <sub>might be phrased slightly different, like "import from internal storage"</sub>

Comment: Dear Izzy. Thanks for your answer. I wrote this issue after many attempts using the CONTACTS and the import command. It starts working, but there is no outcome.

Comment: So something is wrong with either your VCF file or your contacts app, it seems. To include an alternative approach: are you open to use Google stuff for that? Or some self-hosted software on your PC (I'm thinking of ownCloud/Nextcloud here)?

Comment: Dear Izzy, I think that the whole installation of the  phone was bad. Maybe is to ignore this installation(I think that the vendor has revised it), and install a fresh one. How to do that? BTW,  Can I interest you with new technology which enhance performance and reduce power consumption. How to pass it to you? Best regards, Yehuda

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "install a fresh one", please see our [installation tag-wiki](/tags/installation/info) (the "firmware" section) or our [factory-reset tag-wiki](/tags/factory-reset/info). If neither answered that question, be welcome to [ask a new question](/questions/ask). A Q&A site works a bit different than a forum, so we don't switch topics on the same page :)